# Android, get views "All" background properties

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I used `view.getBackground()` to get my `EditText`'s background and then set it again to that `EditText`, but the problem is that the background is similar to edittext default background except that other edittexts default backgrounds goes green when has focus but my gotten background doesn't change its color! (EditText is android default editText that introduced at material design).

Comment: Do you need to change the background to custom color on focus?

Comment: I have several EditTexts user can see the difference between this and those!

Comment: you should use custom drawable for background for different states.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom EditText.

**edit_text.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
 
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
 
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_pressed" />
 
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_selected" />
 
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_default" />
 
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled_selected" />
 
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/textfield_disabled" />
 
</selector>
```

And in your **activity_main.xml** define EditText.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/edit1_text"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_text" />
```

You will see this type of EditText.

[image]

Customize this as per your needs.

Comment: I want to use default edittext ! I think it has tint that I can't grab!